# Are there any graphic design societies/clubs for experienced designers in the UK?

Tags: community, collaboration

One thing I miss about college is the opportunities the societies and clubs offered in terms of work and collaboration with other designers in a passive way.

This is my hobby, not just my job so I was wondering are there any clubs or societies that people would suggest I could join. Of course I am quite aware of online communities and magazines to follow but sometimes it's nice to have good old face to face contact.

Suggestions appreciated. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My best suggestion is

## [Meetup](http://www.meetup.com/)

I have experience with the various tech-and-design groups in a few different countries, they have all been between good and excellent. The meetups span from geekbeer (exactly what it says) to major (free) gettogethers with interesting topics, presentations and lectures.

**Edit:**
There are other similar networks, but to date I have not found any better. However, I found this thing; **[PeopleHunt,](http://thenextweb.com/apps/2013/01/09/peoplehunt-this-new-iphone-app-is-like-meetup-for-spontaneous-get-togethers/)** an iPhone app that facilitates spontaneous meetings of people with similar interests. It seems a pretty cutting edge thing, and probably not working in Europe at the moment. I am a little sceptical, but hey. It might be the bees knees (also, I do not have an iPhone).

Comment: This is looking great it's got such a variety, thanks Boblet! I'm having a rummage through it now. I'll let you know how I get along.

Comment: Yea, please do. I am never disappointed with the groups I go to. Since I do not know where in the UK you are, you will have to do the geosearch yourself :-)

Comment: Manchester but I don't mind doing my own searching, just some direction is appreciated. I'll mark you as correct if nothing more relevant pops up soon. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

How about [Bristol Usability Group](http://bristolusability.ning.com/) if you are in the SW - although admittedly this is UX not really graphic design ...